# Is it possible to see the 'null' in the table in sql instead of blank

Tags: sql, oracle, null, oracle10g

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |          |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    |          |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

how to print the null instead of blank space in the above table in id 6,7 for salary column  while inserting the values.

```
 +----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |   null   |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    |   null   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: please post your SQL Insert statement

Comment: How are you "*seeing*" this table?  What query are you using to return the data and what tool/code are you using to display it?

Comment: By default sql `select` statements show nulls instead of blank spaces, are you sure the value in said columns is `null`, not a blank space? (assumming sql server or mysql)

Comment: It depends on WHAT SOFTWARE shows the data set. Also you can return varchar values instead of float and return 'NULL' string in case of null values.

Comment: my sql insert statement is  INSERT INTO table values(6,'Komal',22,'MP',null);<br/> when I use this insert statement null is left blank. can we insert that to null directly

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL() or IFNULL() in your SELECT depending on the RDBMS. Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, ADDRESS, IFNULL(SALARY, "null") FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: while inserting  the values into the table. for example,            insert into table values(7,'Muffy',24,'Indore',null); the null value attribute is left blank, instead is it possible to see the null explicitly in the table(just like in my second table) after inserting values.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle equivalent of neelsg's answer,

```
SELECT id, name, age, address, NVL(salary, "null") FROM yourtable
```